# How to update dynamodb attribute based on a condition on another attribute

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

For ex:

I have:

```
{
 "status": "running",
 "ts": "1590560955"
}
```

If current system ts >= above "ts", then:

```
{
 "status": "completed",
 "ts": "1590560955"
}
```

Is this even possible? Does Lambda function help here? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. It is called a "conditional update" - see for example [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html). You can update one attribute based on the value of a different attribute - if those belong to the *same item*.

Here is an example (in Python, using Amazon's boto3 library, but you can translate it to whichever language you prefer):

```py
table.update_item(
        Key={'p': p},
        UpdateExpression='SET status = :completedl',
        ConditionExpression='ts > :currentts',
        ExpressionAttributeValues={':completed': 'completed', ':currenttts': currentts})
```

This conditionally updates the item with key `p`: If `ConditionExpression` is fullfilled, i.e., the item's `ts` value is higher than "currentts" (which you'll supply), then the update described in `UpdateExpression` takes place: This item's `status` attribute is set to the string 'completed'.

Comment: this works only if we make this request everytime, right? How is this different from computing the comparison logic in a service and just a normal update request? Is there a way this update can happen in an automated way?

Comment: If that's what you want to do every time, you need to make this request every time. There are many benefit of sending a "conditional" update to the server instead of reading and writing. A conditional update is guaranteed atomic with concurrent writes. It is faster and cheaper (it costs the same as an unconditional write! it doesn't add a read's price). There is less client logic to code (is this what you asked about "automated way"?) - just send this ConditionExpression every time.